# Type safety of Boost Qi/X3 parse

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-x3

Consider this code using Boost Spirit X3 (conceptually same goes for Boost Spirit Qi):

```
  string command;
  string value;
  x3::parse(command.begin(), command.end(), "float:" >> x3::double_, value);
```

Why is this code not generating any error during compilation? Shouldn't `"float:" >> x3::double_` parser have attribute of type `double` and therefore not accept `std::string` as 4th argument to `parse`?

BTW, I know I could do this:

```
string value;
auto assign = [](auto& ctx){value = _attr(ctx)};
x3::parse(command.begin(), command.end(), "float:" >> x3::double_[assign], value)
```

which would generate an error, but it is more complicated than necessary.

As a last resort: any there any well-known replacements for `sscanf` that would be type safe (possibly in boost)?

Comment: Please, file a bug, this definitely should not compile.

Comment: Filed bug [here](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because automatic attribute propagation into a container is very flexible.

And `std::string` is a container.

Perhaps if we do the following experiment it makes a bit more sense:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b36379b8272df4bc)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

int main() {
    //std::string command = "f: hello world";
    std::string command = "f: 104 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100";
    std::string value;
    x3::phrase_parse(
            command.begin(),
            command.end(),
            "f:" >> *x3::double_, x3::blank,
            value);

    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

As you might surmise, it prints:

```
hello world
```

For strings this seems surprising. It would be much less of a surprise if the target was `std::vector<float>` - but it would require precisely the same amount of conversions.

It's fair for each element to enjoy propagation conversions. What if you were parsing Ast nodes like:

```
struct Operation {
     Operator op;
     std::vector<Expression> operands;
}
```

You would hate if operands didn't implicitly convert into `Expression` from `Unary`, `FunctionCall`, `StringLiteral` etc.

Comment: In the off-chance you were **really** looking for a way to synthesize the source text _as matched_, use `raw[]`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34635951fbabe59d

Comment: "It's because automatic attribute propagation into a container is very flexible." - is it possible to limit this flexibility using some boost spirit settings? I am asking because in my use case I would like to just have type-safe `sscanf` replacement. And I would expect that this simple mistake (value of type string, not double) would be detected by the compiler.

Comment: That's not what spirit is. It's not geared to be a primitives type token scanner. If you look at the name `scanf` you can glean as much. Maybe you'd like a scanner (Spirit Lex) or a much simpler pattern expression library like Boost Xpression. But I think what you're describing doesn't yet exist (and would be the dual complement of libfmt). Perhaps there merit in starting an open source initiative;)

Comment: Boost Xpression doesn't have the notion of `double`/`float`, Lex seems too complicated, and libfmt uses format string which is not any better than `sscanf`. I'll probably stick to good old `sscanf`. Anyway, seems compilers have good support for checking mismatched format strings.

Comment: @sehe, it is **very** "surprising" that the parsed value is "hello world".  I don't see how any user, not **very** intimate with the initricacies of x3 attribute propagation, would not also be **very** surprised.  IMHO, this makes x3 attribute propagation a liability rather than an asset, and I agree that there should be "an open source initiative" to remedy this.

Comment: @user1681377 I know right. I believe that's exactly what I've been saying. I also explained exactly why it still makes sense. If you don't like it, don't look at me. I didn't write any of it - I just use it. If you run a lot of PoC parsers to ASTs (not primitive types) you ***will*** come to appreciate this. It's a static type mapping so a test coverage suffices to know that it does what you want/expct.

Comment: By the way, your claim about libfmt (_"and libfmt uses format string which is not any better than sscanf"_) is [wrong](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html#safety). People don't give generics the credit it deserves.

Comment: @sehe, I now understand your answer after reading and responding to Joel's answer [here](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/618#issuecomment-662407786).  In essense, each time x3::double_ is parsed, the resulting double is converted to a char and that char is push_backed onto the `std::string value`.

Comment: I thought I had made that "clear" by literally leaving the comment _`//std::string command = "f: hello world";`_ right above the line that shows those letters in ASCII ordinals :) Sorry for assuming that was clear

Comment: @sehe , your help in reaching a consensus in the [spirit issue #618](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/618) would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

@tomasz-grobelny, using the `explicit_convert_parser_type` from
[here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d411e76f063a746), and with `#defined REPRODUCE_SO_62986317`, correctly compile-time
errors when passing anything but a `double` as the attribute.

HTH,

Larry

Comment: OOPS, when the grammar argument changed to
`"float:">>explicit_convert_parser_type<decltype(x3::double_)>{},
x3::blank`, the last test no longer compiles.  Maybe it has
something to do with the comment: "sequence collapsing
activates for sequence length of one" made
[here](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/618#issuecomment-662419631);
however, I'm not sure because I'm not real familiar with the
"intricacies" of spirit x3 attribute collapsing :( .

Comment: The problem has been corrected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab1802d65b65b8b7).  @sehe, your requirements are shown satisfied by running test<dbl2int> and tomasz-grobelny, your requirements (for diagnosing type error) are shown by running test<tbl2dbl> when defined(REPRODUCE_SO_62986317).  Or am I missing something?